# Javascript: turn an array of keys into an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, recursion

I know this is probably easier than my brain is making it, but for some reason, I can't get this right:

I have an array looks like this:

```
["engine", "engine.car", "engine.car.driver", 
 "engine.car.passenger", "wheels", "wheels.tires"]
```

I want to transform above array into this object:

```
{
    engine : {
        car : {
            driver : undefined,
            passenger: undefined
        }
    },
    wheels : {
        tires: undefined
    }
 }
```

I'm using node 8.10.0.

Comment: Did you try something out? Please post where you are stuck.

Comment: Does the array always come sorted? For example, are all properties relating to engine going to be next to each other like in the example or can you have ["engine","wheels","engine.car","wheels.tires",...], because the solutions to this problem can vary.

Comment: no not at all, it can come in any order @user8463863

Comment: @sunil I have nothing of real value to offer as far as "where I'm stuck".  I know the solution is either a recursive algorithm which I am struggling with atm, or a way to access/create a nested property on a hash given the string path of it.

It seems I've been marked redundant via the second solution, so that's great!  No recursion!

Comment: `function transformArrayToObject ( array ) {
  var resultObject = {},
      index, item;

  function _transform ( _array, tmpObject ) {
    if ( _array.length > 1 ) {
      tmpObject[_array[0]] = {};
      return Object.assign(tmpObject, _transform(_array.slice(1), tmpObject[_array[0]]));
    } else return tmpObject[_array[0]] = void 0;
  }
  for ( index = 0; index < array.length; index += 1 ) {
      item = array[index].split('.');
      resultObject[item[0]] = item.length > 1 ? _transform(item.slice(1), {}) : void 0;
  }
  return resultObject;
}`

Comment: Are you looking for something like - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/djOYjP?editors=1010 which can be achieved using forEach and split() method

Answer (score -3):

This is pretty straightforward with JavaScript and the eval functionality. Here is a quick example.

```js
var arr = ["engine", "engine.car", "engine.car.driver",  "engine.car.passenger", "wheels", "wheels.tires"];
 
obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
 eval("obj." + arr[i] + " = {}");
  
console.log(obj);
```

### Edit

Eval is not evil, most implementations of it are but this is a perfectly valid use of it as outlined in the comments below. If you have an issue with this answer please use the comments to let me know why so I can either update the answer or OP can get the help they need.

Comment: using `eval` is a bad idea

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Care to expand on that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn '_Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks_' this isn't data from user input so an injection attack doesn't apply here. '_Debugging can be more challenging (no line numbers, etc.)_' that's a fair argument. '_eval'd code executes slower (no opportunity to compile/cache eval'd code)_' Even it that thread he points out that isn't the issue it used to be. There are no absolutes, this is a perfectly fine use of eval.

Comment: And how do you know this isn't user input?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn because it's in an array

Comment: Which could have been generated from user input...

Comment: Sure, it _could_ have but you just said 'using eval is a bad idea' you have no more information than I do so there is no way you can know if it is a 'bad idea' is all I'm saying. There are certainly valid times to use eval and this is potentially one of them.